# unable to install hyper kit on mac as it is showing an error during a brew intall

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I am unable to install hyper kit on my mac. I am issueing the command brew install hyperkit from the terminal . the following is the logs result

```
Kjango-MacBook-Air:~ kanan$ brew install hyperkit

Warning: You are using macOS 10.12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

hyperkit: A full installation of Xcode.app 9.0 is required to compile
this software. Installing just the Command Line Tools is not sufficient.

Xcode can be installed from the App Store.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Appreciate if you can help me to resolve.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded to the mac os catalina .

then i was able to install it